# Power Platform Import Solution Task From Azure Dev Ops triggers two solutions deploy in CRM

Tags: azure-devops, dynamics-crm, crm, power-platform

Power Platform Import Solution Task From Azure Dev Ops triggers an Import into CRM solution. But about an hour later into the Import there is another entry in the solution history of CRM for the same solution. This causes the ADO task to fail.

As seen in the below image there are two entries. The second fails as the first one is still in progress.

[image: Solution History]

Tried using the latest task version 2.0 from the ADO.
[image]

Comment: you might want to add your devops pipeline tasks and in addition is there any automatic trigger taking place of deployment? I would say stop/deactivate any automatic trigger of deployment.

Comment: auto trigger is for creating a release. but the stage releases are approval based.

Comment: looks pretty staright forward, could you pin point there actually is 2 deployment. one more question do you need solution upgrade? could you try without it and if it works may be try adding solution upgrade and see if your issue persist?

Comment: import is with a holding solution and then the solution upgrade.
So when the Import task is running after 2 hours there is an extra import that comes up in the solution history of CRM. Not sure what triggers that

Comment: were you managed to solve this?